# How do you say 感谢台前幕后队友们的功劳努力 in English?

Tags: translation

Let's say we have successfully completed a project and as a project manager, you would like to thank the entire project members i.e. those facing the client and those working quietly behind the scenes for their effort especially the latter group of members which is always being forgotten. Is there an English expression for this?

Comment: What you wrote is fine, "those facing the client and those working quietly behind the scenes".  [I'd avoid "frontstage" / "backstage" (unless it's about e.g. a theater company) in preference for "front-office" / "back-office" or "front-facing" / "non-front-facing".]

Answer (score 2):

感谢台前幕后队友们的功劳努力。
Thank you all for the great contribution you made, both front-stage and back-stage.

Or, more simply: Thank you all for your hard work!

Comment: Could "visible" and "invisible" work in this context?

Comment: A big thank you to all who contributed to this project, both those whose contributions were publicly visible and those behind the scenes who made everything work so smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

(Many) Thanks to the efforts and contributions from the frontstage and backstage teammates.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone who has contributed their part in this. Shout out to ...{your PART 1 audience here, e.g. front-stage staff}, and hats down for {PART 2}